# Some images not displaying in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have recently redesigned my website.  For me it works fine for IE, FF and Chrome - on multiple PC's.  A few users though (using Chrome) report broken image links, little boxes where images should be.

I've advised and instructed them how to check from for update and also clear cookies/cache.

What could be the problem for this? Perhaps it's my code, but I don't think it is server side because it works for 95% of users.   I appreciate all help.

(Here is the part of the code that contains the info not displaying. I use php include on home page to include this file. If you need more code let me know, Thanks.)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="content/style/site.css" type="text/css"/>
<div>
<div class="arrowgreen">
<ul>
<li><a href="/index.php" title="Home"><img src="images/schedule.png" alt="" height="23" align="middle" border="0" width="120"></a></li>
<li><a href="/espn.php"><img src="images/espn.png" alt="" height="23" align="middle" border="0" width="120"></a></li>
<li><a href="/espn2.php"><img src="images/espn2.png" alt="" height="23" align="middle" border="0" width="120"></a></li>
<li><a href="/golfchannel.php"><img src="images/golfchannel.png" alt="" height="23" align="middle" border="0" width="120"></a></li>
<li><a href="/nbatv.php"><img src="images/nbatv.png" alt="" height="23" align="middle" border="0" width="120"></a></li>
<li><a href="/nflnetwork.php"><img src="images/nflnetwork.png" alt="" height="23" align="middle" border="0" width="120"></a></li>
<li><a href="/nhlnetwork.php"><img src="images/nhlnetwork.png" alt="" height="23" align="middle" border="0" width="120"></a></li>
<li><a href="/bigbrother.php"><img src="images/bigbrother.png" alt="" height="23"  align="middle" border="0" width="120"></a></li>
<li><a href="/channel1.php">CHANNEL 1</a></li>
<li><a href="/channel2.php">CHANNEL 2</a></li>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Open your console when browsing the web page. Tell us if there are any errors popping up.

Comment: Is your image data corrupted at all? I recall having to reupload images when having a similar problem with Chrome. I had just assumed that Chrome is more finicky about image data, but never really looked into it.

Comment: As an FYI you're missing the closing </ul> tag. I doubt that would cause any issues but maybe some older versions of Chrome were a bit more strict with markup.

Comment: I'd suggest also looking at the network tab of Chrome's web inspector to see what response these images return when it attempts to load them.

Comment: Are you (or the users who have the problem) using an ad blocker?

Comment: Hi guys.  I don't see anything bad in the console. Some errors, but none relavant to whats happened. [link]http://serioussportstv.net[/link] is the home page if anyone wants to look for themselves.

Comment: Someone sent a picture of their issues. It appears to be css related.  Is there a reason why chrome wouldn't load the style sheet right on some machines?

Answer (score 0):

So if the image is there it should display unless it is blocked (based on domain) by firewalls etc.  I've seen this happen where images were correctly located in the path specified, but were blocked by a firewall.

I've also, seen images that take too long to load show as broken, even though the links are set correctly and they are not blocked by a firewall.

In any case, when an image breaks, it will throw an error which you can catch:

```
window.onerror = function (event) {
    // inspect event.
    // console.log(event)
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Fixed the problem by just putting absolute paths to everything.

Apparently some ppl's browsers wouldn't work otherwise.  Probably update issue with their java or similar. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like I made it too complicated.  I assumed you knew how to set relative paths.  Can you give an example of the absolute path you changed to.